# How to pass variables to Custum view after 1rst onDraw()

Tags: java, canvas

I've been searching for this for a very long time but nothing I found was really helpful... I have an layout with a customView, which gets drawn when the layout is loaded. So in my init() in the Activity I start an TCP-Connection to my Server which returns an ArrayList. I want that ArrayList to be passed throw to the onDraw() where I work with its values. My problem is that I can call a method that sets a local variable to the new value but because of some reason the onDraw() method still uses the empty ArrayList which isnt filled. I think that the code explains it better... Is that the right way to do it or is my approch at first place wrong ?

HistoryActivity:

```
public class HistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView history_List;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    initialize();
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    finish();
    return true;
}

private void initialize(){
    history_List = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.history_List);
    new TCP_Client(new TCP_Client.AsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinish(String[] output) {
            ArrayList<String[]> day_Averrage_History = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            for(String encoded_Array:output){
                day_Averrage_History.add(Encoder.unserialize(encoded_Array));
            }
            Diagramm_Builder diagramm_builder = new Diagramm_Builder(HistoryActivity.this); 
            diagramm_builder.set_Drawing_Parameters(day_Averrage_History);//Here I pass the variable
            diagramm_builder.invalidate();
        }
    }

    ).execute(new String[]{"r","dah","TecHFreaKAV"});
}

}
```

DiagrammBuilder:

```
public class Diagramm_Builder extends View {

public Context ctx;
private ArrayList<String[]> parameters;

public Diagramm_Builder(Context context){
    super(context);
}

public Diagramm_Builder(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public void set_Drawing_Parameters(ArrayList<String[]> given_Parameters){
    parameters = given_Parameters;
}

public Diagramm_Builder(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    ctx = this.getContext();
}

public ArrayList<String[]> get_Drawing_Parameters(){
    try {
        Log.e("Message", "Lenght = " + this.parameters.size());
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        Log.e("Message","Lenght = 0");
    }
    return parameters;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if(get_Drawing_Parameters() == null) {
        Rect test_rect = new Rect();
        test_rect.set(1, 1, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        Paint color = new Paint();
        color.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        color.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawRect(test_rect, color);
    }else{
        Log.e("Message","Recived Array");
    }

}


}
```

The Consule outputs two times E:/Message: Length = 0 which means that the ArrayList does not arrive...

I would be very grateful for any help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with just seting a global Varibale in my HistoryActivity and call setContentView() after the,which gave me the opertunity to just call in onDraw() HistoryActivity.ArrayList